# PHP - Replace exact match preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to implement a *very* simple PDO bindValue() function. (Just for educational purpose)

So, first in the "frontend" code, I have a SQL query like this :

```
INSERT INTO logs VALUES (:referer, :id_cookie, :id_cookie_com);
```

And my code which looks like this :

```
$stmt->bindValue(':referer', 'test');
$stmt->bindValue(':id_cookie', 'test2');
$stmt->bindValue(':id_cookie_com', 'test3');
```

I'm splitting my query, and I'm getting all the parameters that begins with a ":" in an array, that works well.

```
Array
(
    [0] => :referer
    [1] => :id_cookie
    [2] => :id_cookie_com
)
```

But, when I try to replace the parameters in the query, I'm facing a little problem.

If I do this :

```
    public function bindParam($parameter, $variable, $type = null)
    {
       $this->sql = preg_replace('/'.$parameter.'/', $variable, $this->sql);
    }
```

I'm getting this as a result :

```
INSERT INTO logs VALUES (test, test2, test3_com)
```

I can't manage to remove the *_com* at the end of the query. I know why it's here, it's because my preg_replace, matches the id_cookie in my array, and I have to variable that begins with id_cookie.

How can I manage to make preg_replace() replacing the entire word ?

Comment: Cannot replicate: https://eval.in/207173

Comment: In your example, I think you replicated it :
`INSERT INTO logs VALUES (:referer, test2, test2_com);`

Comment: Hahaha, thanks @Kikndanutz! Totally missed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use word boundary:

```
$this->sql = preg_replace("/$parameter\b/", $variable, $this->sql);
//                             here __^^
```

Comment: I tried like this :
`$this->sql = preg_replace("/\b$parameter\b/", $variable, $this->sql);`
Or like this :
`$this->sql = preg_replace('/\b'.$parameter.'\b/", $variable, $this->sql);`
But it replaced nothing... :(